# How to get total size of all memory heaps in a process?

Tags: windows, size, heap-memory

How to get the total size of all memory heaps in a windows process? 

I have read many articles about this but they did not help.

Comment: I'm asking how to get the total size of memory heaps?!?!

Comment: Do you need to find the size for *your* process or *a* process?

Comment: I need the size for my process not other processes (i.e. without using profiler or something like that)

Comment: what is the problem of my question? why it has 3 minus mark?

Answer (score 0):

I would just go ahead and use this. http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/heap_memory_view.html It should help you.

Comment: I found it on google but I want get the total size in my program! this is an external software